# computing the volume of a cylinder using repeated addition?

Tags: java

im trying to make a code block to compute the volume of a cylinder but im unfamiliar with java so this is what i had so far. Is there anyway to re-purpose it so i can compute the volume?

```
package javaapplication231;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaApplication231 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int a,b,i,product;
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the values of a and b: ");
           a = keyboard.nextInt();                       //Line 6
        b = keyboard.nextInt(); 
        i=0;
        product=0;
        while (i<a){
            i=i+1;
            product= product +b;

        }
                System.out.println("Product=" + product);
    }

}
```

V =PIr^2h
               where r is the radius and h is the height
               user input: r and h
                  PI= 3.1416

Comment: What is the problem you are having? You could simply do the calculation that you have written at the bottom, why do you have a loop at all?

Comment: I wouldn't even try.  Just multiply everything you need to multiply, and don't mess around with repeated addition.

Comment: First, PI is not integer, so trivial repeated addition will not be enough at a point. But are at least r and h integers? If yes you can compute r*r*h with repeated additions, and then say that V*10000 is 31416 * (r*r*h).

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the volume of Cylinder simply evaluate the expression, why do you need loop and do the addition. As you mentioned use the formula to calculate the

> Volume=PI*radius<sup>2</sup>*height

```
int radius, height;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the values of radius and Height: ");
radius = keyboard.nextInt(); // Line 6
height = keyboard.nextInt();
double volume = 3.14 * radius * radius * height;
System.out.println("Volume=" + volume);
```